# Is a $\tau$-mixed Weil sheaf always a direct summand of a $\tau$-real sheaf?

Tags: weights, l-adic-sheaves

Fix an isomorphism $\tau: \overline{\mathbf{Q}_\ell} \cong \mathbf{C}$ and consider Weil sheaves on a scheme $X$ over $\mathbf{F_q}$.

It is a theorem that a $\tau$-real sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ is $\tau$-mixed, from which it follows that direct summands of $\mathscr{F}$ are also $\tau$-mixed.

Is the converse true? That is, is any $\tau$-mixed sheaf $\mathscr{G}$ always a direct summand of a $\tau$-real sheaf? If so, how is this proven?

Comment: This is stated to be true on page 37 of [these notes](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~takumim/Weil%20II.pdf). I think it should follow from the result for $\tau$-pure sheaves, which is Lemma 3.14 on page 14.

Comment: I saw the notes. But I did not see a proof.